# After implementing facebook login replaceScene freezes

Tags: objective-c, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

I have implemented facebook login according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1#login-apicalls

I have implemented this functionality in my AppDelegate. instead of `- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender` method I have same code under `-(void)toggleFacebookOnOff;` and accessing it from other classes via `[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] toggleFacebookOnOff];`

When facebook session is NOT open and I call login method i.e my app redirects to facebook app and then back,calling method `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:<#(CCScene *)#> withTransition:<#(CCTransition *)#>]` Freezes whole application, no exceptions, no nothing.

Notes:

1. [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:(CCScene *)]; is still functional.
2. I have noticed that actions are not performed anymore, e.g in different scene I have CCActionEaseInOut to scale sprite from 0.1f to 1.f and this sprite stays scaled.
3. problems are occurring after app redirects to FB app end then beck, no problem is occurring when I call FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions with parameter:  `allowLoginUI:NO`.

Anyone has fix for this issue?

Comment: Has the director been resumed before the attempt to replace the scene has occurred?

Comment: Thanks for reply, what does it mean and how can I check it?

Comment: Your app delegate's applicationDidBecomeActive should be calling resume on the director while applicationWillEnterForeground is calling startAnimation. Are these actually happening and do they happen before you've attempted to replace the scene?